# Where should a pronoun go when the verb is followed by an infinitive clause?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, ordre-des-mots, infinitif

Which variant is correct and why:

> *La peinture. Je le voulais ameliorer.*

OR

> *La peinture. Je voulais l’ameliorer.*

As for me both look correct from the point of grammar. Though the second one is a bit more euphonic. On the other hand, usually one would flip a pronoun and a predicate — and it is the first case.

Comment: Pardon this left field suggestion, but what about “je la voulais améliorée?  That is, if I want to get someone else (not me) to improve it.  Or do I have the wrong end of the stick, and the issue is getting better at la peinture?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what you have written I expect you know the rule that says that when the direct object is a pronoun, it must be placed before the verb.

> J'améliore la peinture → Je l'améliore.

I suppose you hesitate because there are two verbs in your sentence and you do not know in front of which verb (*vouloir* or *améliorer*) to place the pronoun.

*La peinture* is the direct object of *améliorer*, so when you replace la peinture by a pronoun you put it directly before *améliorer*.

> Je voulais améliorer la peinture.  →  Je voulais l'améliorer.

Note that in your first sentence *le* is wrong because peinture is feminine.

> La peinture, je voulais **la** changer.